# is there a query that returns the type of disease based on the symptom

Tags: android

I'm working with an android health application that will display a disease. For I have three tables such as symptoms, diseases and symptom_disease table which will link those two tables. a user enters symptoms such as dizziness, syncope, asthenia, and others, then it will display hypertensive disease.  How can I write the query for this differentiate this thing? and how to implement it.

Comment: Post the CREATE statements of the tables with sample data and expected results to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This easy example of how can be done:-

These tables :-

```
create table if not exists symptoms (id integer primary key, symptom text unique);
create table if not exists diseases (id integer primary key, disease text unique);
create table if not exists symptom_disease (diseaseid integer not null, symptomid integer not null, primary key(symptomid,diseaseid));
```

This the data put into tables :-

```
insert into diseases (disease) values ('cold'),('flu'),('hypertensive disease'),('vertigo');
insert into symptoms (symptom) values('dizziness'),('syncope'),('asthenia'),('headache'),('coughing'),('sorethroat'),('fever');
insert into symptom_disease values (3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(1,4),(2,4),(1,5),(2,5),(1,6),(2,6),(2,7),(4,1);
```

This gets data for disease that have dizziness or syncope or symptom starting with asth :-

```
select disease, count() AS rating
from diseases 
    join symptom_disease on diseases.id = diseaseid 
    join symptoms on symptomid = symptoms.id
where symptom = 'dizziness' or symptom = 'syncope' or symptom like 'asth%'
group by disease
order by rating desc
;
```

it get

```
hypertensive disease    3
vertigo                 1
```

*most likely hypertensive disease as that has 3 symptom*

You could make foreign keys so symptom_disease table cannot have bad data by doing

```
create table if not exists symptom_disease (
    diseaseid integer not null references diseases(id) on delete cascade on update cascade , 
    symptomid integer not null references symptoms(id) on delete cascade on update cascade, 
    primary key(symptomid,diseaseid));
```

You need to turn on Foreign Key for using Foreign key.